# Is it possible to use code push when native code has changed?

Tags: code-push, react-native-code-push

If I add a package that requires changes in the native code, like MainActivity for android, is it still possible to use codepush to update the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible, since code-push runtime on the device can only replace the javascript part and not the native parts.

Comment: That what I thought as well. So adding native code requires a new release on Play Store..